# SAGA not working in QGIS 3.16 on Mac OS 11.2

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, saga, mac

In the Toolbox, the SAGA tools are greyed out, for example:

[image]

I can still double click on the tools and open the dialogue box, although a warning is displayed:

[image]

I've tried a few tools and they will run, apparently correctly (i.e. several seconds pass and the progress bar moves), but then no output is produced.

I have seen several related questions about this on GIS SE and other forums ([here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217414/saga-algorithms-not-working-on-qgis-2-18-on-mac-osx), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202929/problems-with-saga-integration-in-qgis-2-14-4-ltr?rq=1), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380164/integrating-saga-7-8-1-into-qgis-3-16-os-windows-10) etc). There seem to be recurrent issues integrating SAGA with QGIS. However, all the answers and workarounds are either for older versions of software, or for different OS.

Any ideas how to resolve this with my versions and OS?